# How to make Matplotlib figures interactive in a Flask application?

Tags: python, matplotlib, flask, mpld3

I am trying to display spectrograms in a Flask application. I use matplotlib for creating the spectrograms and mpld3 for displaying them in an HTML file with the default toolbar.
The problem is that I am not able to zoom into the same region for each spectrogram at the same time. 
[This is a screenshot of default figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oNv6S.png)
[This is another screenshot that I took after zooming in a little bit on a left top one.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kj3DW.png)
As you can see, all of the y-axes have been changed with the same scale as the left top ones. However, the x-axes of the right top, the left bottom, and the right bottom haven't been changed at all. So what I want to do is to compare those guys with the same scale.
Does anyone have any suggestion such as a better idea to make it possible or maybe the solution for the problem?